# Error in LTspice electronic circuit

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice

When I try to run the circuit show below, I get that error. I've made all the links again and it continues happening. Does anyone know why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can't find the 74HC32 model. Put a .command on the schematic for the model, or a library with it in. You appear to have linked the 4532 library and model. Do they have an HC32 in?

Comment: After you fix the subcircuit error, you'll get a bunch of new errors because all your voltage sources have a value of `V` and aren't defined.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're missing a model in the 74hc32 model or the parameters are not quite right. Double check how you're calling the model from the graphical component. A good way to do this is to check the netlist

Answer (score 0):

LTSpice can't find the sub-circuit for the device U5. If you look at the text in the box, it says XU5, which is the ref-des given to the Device, the rest of text mentions the nets going in to said Device.